# Normalizing params a named route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, normalization, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm again, wrestling with rails 3 and routes.

Here is the problem:

I created a named route like this one for example:

`match '/download/artist/:artist/album/:albumName', :to  => "albums#show", :as => :search, :via => :get` that gives me this route: `search_path`

I also have the classic one like this: 
`get "albums/show"` that gives me this route: `albums_show_path` .

However, when I'm using the search_path with some parameters like this:

`<%= link_to "#{result.name[0..50]}(...)", search_path(:artist =>result, :albumName => result.name), :class => "albumName" %>`

, it fails, but not with the albums_show_path. Here is the error:

`no route matches {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show", :artist=>"Eddie Vedder & Ben Harper", :albumName=>"My City of Ruins / My Father's House (Live) [Benefiting Artists for Peace and Justice Haiti Relief] {Digital 45}"}`

I know it probably is because the albumName parameter is not escaped. But even after trying to escape it with `CGI.escape`, doesn't work. I suppose I have to do it in the route.rb, but I have no clue how.

Do you have any idea on how to do it?

**EDIT**

The error says: no route match etc.
When I don't have a parameter with illegal characters, it find the route.

** EDIT `rake routes` **

`welcome_index GET /welcome/index(.:format) {:controller=>"welcome", :action=>"index"}
 albums_index GET /albums/index(.:format)   {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"index"}
 albums_show GET /albums/show(.:format)     {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show"}
 search GET /download/artist/:artist/album/:albumName(.:format) {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show"}
 albums_show_album_info GET /albums/show_album_info(.:format) {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show_album_info"}
 albums_show_itunes GET /albums/show_itunes(.:format) {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show_itunes"}
 albums_show_spotify GET /albums/show_spotify(.:format) {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show_spotify"}
 albums_show_carrefour GET /albums/show_carrefour(.:format) {:controller=>"albums", :action=>"show_carrefour"}
 root     /(.:format)  {:controller=>"welcome", :action=>"index"}`

Comment: What's the error? I don't see one, really?

Comment: I added some detail. But basically, the error is no route match. But it finds the route when there is no '(' for example.

Comment: What's the output of rake routes?

Comment: I edited the post to show you rake routes

Comment: What is the actual link you are clicking on?

Comment: `<%= link_to "#{result.name[0..50]}(...)", search_path(:artist =>result, :albumName => result.name), :class => "albumName" %>`

Answer (score -1):

You could swap out the illegal characters (whichever ones they are with something like) with gsub:

```
<%= link_to "#{result.name[0..50]}(...)", search_path(:artist =>result, :albumName => result.name.gsub("/","\/").gsub("whateverelse", "newvalue"), :class => "albumName" %>
```

I think that this is because / are interpreted as denoting a path separation (I forget the true name of it) in URLs.  You can also "daisy-chain" gsub if you want; see above.

Comment: I could do that, but I need those characters, as params of my controller's action